# Using Custom Partitioner in KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I was wondering if it's possible to use a custom partitioner class in KSQLDB. In https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/7984 they mentioned a custom partitioner is possible in KSQL but I wasn't able to find any links.

For instance, instead of the existing Murmur2 hashing that is used for partitioning I want to create a custom hashing that leverages Murmur3 instead.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but ksqlDB selects data already written to topics. Therefore, your custom partitioner would be in your initial producer code... Then ksqlDB just reads what it sees

Comment: If you are asking about the un-keyed streams, then It is not doable as of now.